# comparing white space and array

Tags: c

What is wrong with this code?
I'm trying to compare string and white space.

```
void main()
{
    char d;
    int i;
    char* mystring="Vikram Natarajan";
    char c=mystring[0];
    printf("%c\n",c);
    for(i=0;i<100; i++)
    {
        if(mystring[i]==" ")
        {
            d=mystring[i+1];
        }
    }
    printf("%c\n",d);
}
```

Comment: Well you don't say what it must do so how can we know what is wrong?

Comment: There's a lot of things wrong; which one exactly are you asking about? For instance, what is `d` supposed to be? Your string isn't 100 characters long, etc.

Comment: In general, the answer to [What should `main()` return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) is "an `int`" and not `void`.  Microsoft gives you an excuse to use `void`, but portable code avoids that.

Comment: What you want to achieve and what this code is not doing?

Comment: Maybe you're missing a `break;` after the assignment to `d`, but your loop condition is reprehensible (you read out of bounds of the array) and and you don't ensure that `d` is set even if there is no space in the string.

Comment: Thanks all for above comments. I didn't post this one properly.  My apologies for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`if(mystring[i]==" ")`

With

`if(mystring[i]==' ')`

Use a single quote for char comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the correct answer, you could also use [`isspace`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isspace.htm) from `ctype.h`. This function basically checks if the passed character `mystring[i]` is a whitespace or not. So instead of:

```
if(mystring[i]==' ')
```

you could do:

```
if (isspace(mystring[i]))
```